# renewcommand within newcommand

Tags: macros

I have a 2-language doc (arabic and english).  Sometimes it is primarily English, sometimes primarily Arabic.

When the doc was primarily Arabic, I changed the Arabic chapter headings with code (see below) I obtained from @ahmed-el-bokl.

```
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase\value{#1}\or
الأول\or
الثاني\or
الثالث\or
الرابع\or
الخامس\or
\else
أحتاج إلى المزيد من ترقيمات الأبواب بالحروف في ملف \fi}
```

However, some of my documents are primarily English, so I would like to execute Ahmed's code only if a flag (`arabicstudent`) is set, otherwise keep the document English.  To do this I have a `newcommand` called `whichlanguage` inside which is a `renewcommand` which is only called if the flag is set.

Below is my MWE.  But xetex sees the `#1` inside the inner `renewcommand` and complains that I did not specify arguments in the outer `newcommand`.

How do I fix this?

```
\newcommand{\whichlanguage}
{
\ifarabicstudent
\setmainlanguage{arabic}

    %here is Ahmed's code again
    \gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}}
    \def\xwords#1{\ifcase\value{#1}\or
    الأول\or
    الثاني\or
    الثالث\or
    الرابع\or
    الخامس\or
    \else
    أحتاج إلى المزيد من ترقيمات الأبواب بالحروف في ملف \fi}

\else
\setmainlanguage{english}
\fi

}
```

Comment: When defining macros within macros you must add a `#`. In this case `##1` instead of `#1`.

Comment: Yes, this works.  Can you put this as an answer and I'll vote for it.

Comment: happy to have the question removed since duplicate.